# What permissions do I need in order to check out a page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions

I'm redesigning a page for my team's Sharepoint site. However, I am not able to check out the page for some reason. I have Full Control permissions for the site and thought that would be enough, but that does not seem to be true. What permissions should I request so that I can check out the page and check it back in when I am done with my changes?

[image: my permissions]

[image: missing check out option]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the URL, you can find the page library to which this page belongs.

Eg:

If the page url is http://sp/sites/team/SitePages/test.aspx, the page is exits in the site pages library.

if the page url is http://sp/sites/team/Pages/test.aspx, the page is exists in the pages library.

Remove test.aspx from the url, it will navigate to the library to which this page belongs.

Then you can go to library settings->versioning settings->choose yes for "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited":

[image]

Comment: Thank you! All I needed to do was find the page library this was a part of so I could allow versioning.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that versioning is enabled on that pages library?
As far as I recall the Contribute permissions level should be sufficient

Comment: Here is Link which describes the exact way to enable the Check Out functionality: http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-document-management/enable-check-in-check-out-versioning-sharepoint-document-library.htm

Comment: It's possible it may not be. How can I find the page library to which this page belongs so that I can check that?

Comment: The link Christian Herzler provided shows how: Navigate to the SharePoint document library on which you want to enable version control.On the Settings menu, click Document Library Settings.On the Customize page under General Settings, click Versioning settings.